# Spark Structured Streaming -

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to run the following code from IntelliJ idea  to print messages from Kafka to console. But it throws the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Stacktrace started from `Dataset.checkpoint` and way up. If I remove `.checkpoint()` then I get some other error - related to permission

```
17/08/02 12:10:52 ERROR StreamMetadata: Error writing stream metadata StreamMetadata(4e612f22-efff-4c9a-a47a-a36eb533e9d6) to C:/Users/rp/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-2f570b97-ad16-4f00-8356-d43ccb7660db/metadata
java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Users\rp\AppData\Local\Temp\temporary-2f570b97-ad16-4f00-8356-d43ccb7660db\metadata
```

Source:

```scala
def main(args : Array[String]) = {
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkStreaming").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  val canonicalSchema = new StructType()
                          .add("cid",StringType)
                          .add("uid",StringType)
                          .add("sourceSystem",
                              new StructType().add("id",StringType)
                                              .add("name",StringType))
                          .add("name", new StructType()
                                        .add("firstname",StringType)
                                        .add("lastname",StringType))


val messages = spark
                    .readStream
                    .format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
                    .option("subscribe","c_canonical")
                    .option("startingOffset","earliest")
                    .load()
                    .checkpoint()
.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),canonicalSchema))
.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start.awaitTermination

 }
```

Can anyone please help me understand where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try running IntelliJ as administrator.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Structured Streaming doesn't support `Dataset.checkpoint()`. There is an open ticket to provide a better message or just ignore it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20927
2. IOException probably is because you don't install cygwin on Windows.

Comment: While Structured Streaming doesn't support `checkpoint()`, it does support `option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/store")`. What would you say that's called?

Comment: Updated the answer. Unfortunately, they use the same word but they are totally different things.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can find the actual meaning of `checkpointLocation` and how it differs?

Comment: "checkpointLocation" is the place where Structured Streaming stores its metadata and running states so that it can restart from a failure. "Dataset.checkpoint" is for a non-streaming Dataset, it just stores the current content of Dataset into the file system (set by SparkContext.setCheckpointDir) so that it don't need to store the whole large logical plan. It doesn't support recovery.

Comment: That should definitely be documented.

Comment: @zsxwing So what needs to be done to get it working? Remove the dataset.checkpoint() and install cygwin?

Comment: Yes, I think so.